# Stop query if there Is an error (Parse.com)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

At the moment the app it crashing if there is no internet connection when running the query. How do I tell the query to stop if there is an error and prevent this? 
Thanks

Error Below:

`Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x1702e0d80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1742569e0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.} (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.21)
2014-12-01 20:36:39.257 AppName[5903:999805] Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.546502 seconds.`

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the crash?

Comment: @rickerbh I have added the code above.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that's the error message, not the code that's causing the problem. You need to post the code that is executed when that error is encountered (your query, and the handler - i.e. the block or callback/selector method)

Comment: Oh okay. I am not entirely sure. I will take a look and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

In parse there you can handle errors for many things.

I think to stop a query if there is not internet connection you can use `kPFErrorConnectionFailed`

Ex.

```
var query = PFQuery()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
(success:Bool!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {

                      //continue query
                    }
                    else{

                        if(error.code == kPFErrorConnectionFailed) {
                            //handle error

                        }


                }     

        }
```

Comment: This is implemented in swift